# Trying to write javascript function to animate scrollTo method

Tags: javascript, timeout

I am new to Javascript and would like to know if the following function should create a transition scrolling down to a set scroll position and if not, what am I misunderstanding about the time out or scroll to methods..

```
    function scrollDownToMovie() {
    for (var scrollbit = 10; scrollbit < 900; scrollbit += 10) {            
            window.setTimeout(function({window.scrollTo(0,scrollbit);}
            ,scrollbit*100); 
            }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: scrollTo() won't fire if the page doesn't already require a scrollbar. In other words, there has to be something to scroll to. Check that first.

Comment: Hi @Nikki, the scrollTo() method does fire, only it sends it straight to the coordinates, not in steps as I had hoped it would with this script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's not perfect but it should do what you want.

```
var scrollbit=10;
function scrollDownToMovie() {

        var time=setTimeout(function(){scrollDownToMovie();},50); //fifty can be whatever  increment you want.
         window.scrollTo(0,scrollbit);scrollbit+=10;
         if(scrollbit>890){clearTimeout(time);}
}
```